# In showing the convergence of a sequence, does it matter how one chooses $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am doing an exercise in *Abbott's Understanding Analysis* textbook (question 2.2.1.b).

> I want to show that: $\displaystyle\lim\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}=\frac{3}{2}.$

Now, i've begun by first working with the inequality I need: $\displaystyle\left|\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right| < \epsilon.$

Simplifying the LHS, I get the inequality: $\displaystyle\left|\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\frac{13}{2|2n+5|} < \epsilon.$

Now my reasoning is as follows. If I start with an $\epsilon$ larger than $\displaystyle\frac{13}{2|2n+5|}$, certainly it would satisfy the original inequality I want. Then I can simply solve for $n$ here to find out how big I need $n$ to be given some $\epsilon$.

Now, testing it out I chose $\epsilon=0.01$, my inequality tells me I need $n>325$ so that my sequence is in this $\epsilon$ neighborhood.

But with a simpler inequality, I can have: $$\displaystyle\left|\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\left|\frac{3n+1}{2n}-\frac{3n}{2n}\right|=\frac{1}{2n}<\epsilon.$$

Now I notice that with this more "optimal" inequality, I just need $n>50$. Of course my first choice with $n>325$ would allow my sequence to be in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood I wanted, but $n>50$ for the first one isn't good enough.

Technically, does it matter how one chooses the inequality? would the first one have been proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one would be fine. As long as you prove that **for sufficiently large values of n, $\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}<\epsilon$** then you're done. It doesn't matter how large $n$ needs to be. As long as it is proved for sufficiently large $n$, no matter what the bound is the proof is fine.

However, on re-look there is a mistake in your second proof. You say

$$\displaystyle\left|\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\left|\frac{3n+1}{2n}-\frac{3n}{2n}\right|=\frac{1}{2n}$$

but actually, $\left|\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}\right|<\left|\frac{3}{2}\right|$ for sufficiently large $n$, which means that the LHS is actually $-\left(\displaystyle\frac{3n+1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right)$. I can't see many ways to make the limit much simpler to evaluate (unless you divide the numerater and denominator by $n$).

Comment: Hmm shouldn't the inequality for the second proof actually be right since the denominator with the $5$ is larger, hence $\frac{3n+1}{2n+5} < \frac{3n+1}{2n}$?

Comment: Oh oops, I think I gave the wrong reason for why that fails. I'll edit it in, hold on